# Spring WebFlux - Why I have to wait for WebClient response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a my WebClient class as per below:

```
public class WebClientSample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(mySimpleTestMethod());
    }

    public static String mySimpleTestMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        String uri = "http://localhost:8080/some/cool/api/here";
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(uri);
        Mono<String> result = webClient
                .get()
                .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth("admin", "secret"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
        String responseStr = result.subscribe(response -> System.out.println(response)).toString();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return responseStr;
    }

}
```

After execution I get this on my console:

```
{"some":{"cool":json,"response":{"foo":"bar",...}}}
reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber@60b71e8f
```

**Question:** If I comment  `Thread.sleep(1000);` then I dont get any response. Why do I need to wait for the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working with `Thread.sleep(1000);` because you are blocking the parent thread for some time and within this time you are getting a response back from WebClient.

WebClient is a non-blocking HTTP client. As you need to return the response back from the `mySimpleTestMethod` method, you need to block until you retrieve the response using `Mono#block()`.

```
String responseStr = result.block();
```

and then you can return the response back.

Also, note that in the below code you are calling `toString` on Disposable type (LambdaMonoSubscriber), LambdaMonoSubscriber doesn't override `toString` method, as a result, you are getting string value (`reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber@60b71e8f`) from toString method of the Object class.

```
String responseStr = result.subscribe(response -> System.out.println(response)).toString();
```

Comment: If I am going to use result.block(); then it will become a blocking request. Isn't it? And wouldnt it defeat the purpose of using Non-Blocking paradigm? But I am still waiting on - Why it works with Thread.sleep(1000); and not without it.

Comment: @AjayKumar it's working with Thread.sleep(1000); , because `sleep(...)` is blocking the parent thread. Thread.sleep(1000); within 1000 milliseconds n/w is getting completed

Comment: Ahh.. got it now @Govinda.!! Thanks a lot.